# Failure to start X server on a HP ZBook

Tags: 16.04, xorg

I keep getting the following error when the X server is trying to start:

```
NMI Watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU4 stuck for 23! [Xorg:1483]
```

Is this a driver issue?  I'm running Ubuntu server 16.04 on a HP ZBook.